# Java application wanting to use both Inet4Address and Inet6Address at the same time

Tags: java, sockets, ipv6, ipv4, inetaddress

I have a Java application that needs to connect via sockets to two different servers on two separate machines.  One server has been configured to listen on IPv4 connections, while the other has been configured to listen on IPv6 connections.

Now, assuming "host1" is the machine name of the server listening on IPv4 connections, while "host2" is the machine name of the server listening on IPv6 connections.  I need to get an `Inet4Address` for "host1" and an `Inet6Address` for "host2" to create a socket connection to each server, such as the following:

```
Inet4Address inet4 = (Inet4Address)InetAddress.getByName("host1");
InetSocketAddress soc4 = new InetSocketAddress(inet4, 7777);
...

Inet6Address inet6 = (Inet6Address)InetAddress.getByName("host2");
InetSocketAddress soc6 = new InetSocketAddress(inet6, 7777);
...
```

However, the JVM by default prefers to use IPv4 addresses over IPv6 addresses for backward compatibility reasons.  So, in the above code, the first attempt to connect to "host1" succeeds, but the second attempt to connect to "host2" fails because `InetAddress.getByName("host2")` returns an `Inet4Address` instead of `Inet6Address`.

I understand that I can set the system property `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` to true to prefer IPv6 addresses over IPv4, but this in turn causes the second attempt to connect to "host2" succeeds, but the first attempt to connect to "host1" failed(!) because `InetAddress.getByName("host1")` returns an `Inet6Address` instead of `Inet4Address`.

The system property `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` is only being read once (see InetAddress line 212-218) and so it would have no effects even if I change its value back to false after setting it to true.

So what I can I do in this case?  This seems like a common problem, so surely there has to be a way already to do it.

Note that I can of course use `InetAddress.getByAddress()` and supply each machine's IP address explicitly instead to get back an `Inet4Address` and `Inet6Address`, but I do not want to do this unless I really have to.  So other solutions please.

Oh, I am using java 1.6.0_19 in case it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static Inet6Address getInet6AddressByName(String host) throws UnknownHostException, SecurityException
{
    for(InetAddress addr : InetAddress.getAllByName(host))
    {
        if(addr instanceof Inet6Address)
            return (Inet6Address)addr;
    }
    throw new UnknownHostException("No IPv6 address found for " + host);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `Inet6Address.getAllByName("host2")`.

this must return IPv6 addres of host, that can be used to create socket.

Comment: `Inet6Address` doesn't have a specific implementation of `getAllByName(String)`, so calling `Inet6Address.getAllByName(String)` is really the same as calling the parent's static method `InetAddress.getAllByName(String)`.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a specific need for methods only available in `Inet6Address` or `Inet4Address` you shouldn't use these classes directly, instead use `InetAddress`.

This way you won't need to cast and risk to have a CCE.

In your case I don't really see good reasons to use specifically IPv6 or IPv4 classes.

Remember, IPv6 is compatible with IPv4, so you don't really have to worry when you use an IPv4 address with an IPv6 system.

---

**Resources :**

- [IPv6 transition mechanisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanisms)
- [Networking IPv6 User Guide for J2SDK/JRE 1.4](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/)

Comment: I do. As I said, the two servers are listening to IPv4 and IPv6 connections respectively.  The casting I did in the sample code above was just to show that I wanted (and I need to) get an `Inet6Address` which I then need to pass to `InetSocketAddress` to connect to "host2" (passing an `Inet4Address` will cause a connection failure).  So, even though I just use the superclass `InetAddress` all the time, underneath it is actually either `Inet4Address` or `Inet6Address`, isn't it?  And in this case, I wanted to make it obvious the problem I am having by doing the casting explicitly.

Comment: Yes, it will still `Inet4Address` only or `Inet6Address`, and what is the problem with it? IPv6 is compatible with IPv4 there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, because that's not what I experienced. I can't use an `Inet6Address` (or `InetAddress` if you like) to connect to the server listening on IPv4 connection - I get a connection failure. This: `new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 7777)` with `InetAddress.getByName("host1")` returning an Inet6Address/InetAddress, won't work. But if `InetAddress.getByName("host1")` returns an `Inet4Address/InetAddress`, it would work.

Comment: I don't really see the problem here, but after looking at this article : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/ It seems that it should work without any cast or whatsoever

Comment: I don't know if it is my machine that is wrong, but I still couldn't use InetAddress (which is Inet6Address underneath) to connect to the server listening on IPv4 connections.  In case it matters, the client and server machines are all Windows XP.

Comment: -1, this answer is misleading. IPv6 is not compatible with IPv4 in every way. You have to think of them as separate stacks that can't talk to each other. Sometimes, someone might wish to get an address of a specific type. See [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.1) (IPv4-compatible addresses deprecated) and current [transition mechanisms](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4213).